# Bootstrap: Inline Form with button unaligns when navbar collapses

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Been trying to learn Web Development and am currently messing around with BootStrap 4.0. I have a search field to the right of the navbar which is inline until the dimensions change to that of a phone and my nav links collapse. In the new format my search field and button are no longer inline. To be clear at tablet dimensions it works fine just not at what I would consider phone size. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!-- NavBar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and Name -->
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="https://logoobject.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/2018/02/Free-Coffee-Logo-1-820x820.png" width = "30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
            Koffee
        </a>
        <!-- For hamburger menu -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <!-- Collapsable nav -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Left hand side content use margin-right (mr) -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <!-- Active Link -->
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active">About Us</a></li>

                <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle = "dropdown" aria-haspopup = "true" aria-expanded = "false">Features</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby = "navbarDropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Cultural</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">The best Cocoa</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">For the workers</a>
                        <!-- Just a line :) -->
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Pricing</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <!-- Disabled link -->
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link disabled">Reviews</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Right Hand side content use margin-left (ml) -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <form class="form-inline">
                    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Go!</button>
                </form>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/wL0ph341/1/)

Comment: If I understood correctly you want search field and button on the same line on mobile screens too?

Comment: @AliaksandrSushkevich that would be correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`d-flex`** instead of `form-inline` for the search form...

https://jsfiddle.net/ahotm7uv/

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <form class="d-flex">
            <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Go!</button>
        </form>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks this works exactly as wanted, cheers for the demo makes it a lot easier to test+

Answer (score 0):

These are parts of styles that are applied to your `.form-control` class:

```
.form-control {
    width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 576px)
.form-inline .form-control {
    width: auto;
}
```

By default it has `width: 100%` which is not what you want. But when the screen size is getting bigger than 576px `width: auto` overlaps it. So changing the default `width: 100%` to `width: auto` should do the trick.